# Moving all folders and subfolders from one drive to another drive using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

Iam using Powershell script to Move folders from one Drive to another.

Here is what i have tried.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse "C:\Personal"  | where-object {$_.lastwritetime -gt '5-25-2015'} | foreach {move-item "$($_.FullName)" "D:\Personal"}
```

This is working if i am moving files within same drive i.e either from cdrive to c drive or d drive to d drive.
But this is not working when iam trying to move from c drive to d drive,...iam getting error like

```
Move-Item : The file exists.
At line:1 char:113
+ Get-ChildItem -Recurse "C:\Development"  | where-object {($_.lastwritetime -lt (get-date))} | foreach {move-item <<<<
"$($_.FullName)" "D:\Development1"}
+ CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Development\test3.txt:FileInfo)  [Move-Item], IOException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId :  MoveFileInfoItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

Please correct me..

Comment: This is working for me `gci -recurse $env:temp | foreach {move-item "$($_.Fullname)" "D:\temp"}`. What error do you get?

Comment: You are moving everything from your subfolders into one folder and there's a name collission. You either have to tell powershell to force an overwrite but I assume you want to include the folder structure when moving so David's answer is spot on. You should try that.

Comment: when i used Move-item instead of Copy-Item from your code all my folders are getting copied and my files are being moved.I want The folders also to be moved instead of copy. Please correct me. Please check my edited code in your answer which iam talking about @LievenKeersmaekers

Answer (score 2):

What means "this is not working"?

The recurse flag seems to indicate you want to copy a directory structure. This will only work if your target directory already has the same structure as your source. If not, you have to create it along the way. Something like this would work:

```
function Move-Directories 
{
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [string] $source,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [string] $destination        
    )

    try
    {
        Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse -Force |
            Where-Object { $_.psIsContainer } |
            ForEach-Object { $_.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape($source), $destination } |
            ForEach-Object { $null = New-Item -ItemType Container -Path $_ }

        Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse -Force |
            Where-Object {  (-not $_.psIsContainer) -and ($_.lastwritetime -ge (get-date)) } |
            Move-Item -Force -Destination { $_.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape($source), $destination }
    }

    catch
    {
        Write-Host "$($MyInvocation.InvocationName): $_"
    }
}
```

With a call like this:

```
Move-Directories "c:\personal" "d:\personal"
```

Comment: Can you please also tell me how to move files lasmodified 30 days back @David Brabant

Comment: add your condition to the Where-Object clause in the second Get-ChildItem call.

Comment: when i used Move-item instead of Copy-Item from your code all my folders are getting copied and my files are being moved.I want The folders also to be moved instead of copy. Please correct me. Please check my edited code in your answer which iam talking about @David Brabant

Comment: Please reply am in great need  @David Brabant